# Count() keeps on giving me 0 even though there is a row returned

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Okay so, i have an enrollment website and part of it prevents the user from re-enrolling the class.

My code goes like this(originally):

```
if (sbj.enroll != sbj.max)                                                                        //check if the subject is not full this time
{
var query = (from subj in emp.SelSubj where subj.studid == st.id && subj.studid == sbj.id select subj); //now check if the user already enrolled that subject code with his id
int x = query.Count();                                                                                 //convert it to number

if (x == 0)                             //subject is not duplicate
{
  sl.studid = st.id;                      //get the student's id then set it
  sl.subjid = sbj.id;                     //get the subj's id then set it
  sl.status = "P";                        //set the initial status to P
  emp.SelSubj.Add(sl);                    //add it to the database ofc
  sbj.enroll++;
  emp.SaveChanges();                      //save changes
  sb.Append(sbj.subj + " ");              //append the log
  TempData["success"] = sb.ToString();    //activate tempdata if there is atleast one subjects
}
else
{
duplicate.Append(sbj.subj + " ");                    //if the user failed the duplicate, append the subject 
TempData["duplicate"] = duplicate.ToString();       //activate tempdata if there is atleast one duplicates
}
}
```

Last night, it was working fine but when i tested it again it doesn't anymore.

Normally, it's just simple, what i need to do is just count the rows returned, if it's `0` then there are no duplicates. I can do that by using `Count()` but it doesn't work anymore.

I decided to check the values per breakpoint.

Results:

First value is 
[image]

while the second is

[image]

I decided to rerun the query to check:
[image]

so there should be a row but the `Count()` keeps on giving me `0` thus allowing the user to re-enroll the subject(which they shouldn't be)

My program will work if i change it to `if(query == null)` but i wanna know why does it keep on giving me 0? I swear it was working fine last night.

[image]

Comment: You should run sql profiler to find the query fired while debugging instead of assuming the query.

Comment: Please chose your tags more carefully. This is not about asp.net-mvc at all.

Comment: An additional note: if you have some number of pennies in a jar, and you wish to know if there are *any* pennies in the jar, do you have to count them to know?  Using `Count()` can be very inefficient; it sometimes actually has to count all the pennies. If all you care about is whether there are zero or non-zero, use `Any()`. It just checks to see if there is at least one, rather than counting them all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is incorrect

```
 where subj.studid == st.id && subj.studid == sbj.id // both refer to studid
```

should be

```
 where subj.studid == st.id && subj.subjid== sbj.id
```

Strongly recommend you follow normal naming conventions to minimise the risk of error like this (i.e. your fields should be named `StudentId` and `SubjectId`)

Comment: Oh wow i didn't catch that and yes i need work on my naming conventions. Thank you so much.